# Setting default .aspx page access?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Sorry for some ambiguous title. I'll try best to explain in detail.

So I'm making page in board to move through from the first page to the next, by using `<a href>` tag in front side, `List.aspx`

the part of code looks like below.

```
<% 
    for (int x = 1; x < page_count + 1; x++)
    {  
%>
        <a name="page_index" href="List.aspx?page=<%=x %>"><%=x %></a>

<% } %>
```

So by using `GET` method, I move the page info to back side, `List.aspx.cs` and here, works with query sentence, calling 10 records from my `MSSQL DB`

```
page_number = Request.QueryString["page"];

        int_page_number = Convert.ToInt32(page_number);
        string sql = ""; //sql query

        CDatabase _db = new CDatabase();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ArticleIdx) AS orderednumber,";
        string tail = "ArticleIdx, writerName, passwords, title, content, writeDate From dbo.article) AS ordering WHERE orderednumber BETWEEN " +(10*(int_page_number-1)+1).ToString() + " AND " + (10*int_page_number).ToString();
        sql = sql + tail;
```

However, the problem is since I set up as default page `List.aspx` if I just enter through my local server, in List.aspx page there appears nothing in my board. If I click number 1 `href tag` below, then it moves to `List.aspx?page=1` and show 10 contents.

How can I connect default `List.aspx` page to page=1?

Comment: You should be using parameters in your SQL instead of concatenating the string. You are very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with your code as it stands.

Comment: I'm using local server and those are not for actual upload. Its just for study. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: Get into the habit of using parameters now so that it is second nature when it is time for the real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the querystring exists first, if it doesn't, set page number to 1 before the rest of your code runs

```
If (Request.QueryString["page"] == "") {
    page_number = 1;
}
else {
    page_number = Request.QueryString["page"];
}
```

edit:
could even do this if you wish

```
page_number = Request.QueryString["page"];
if (page_number == "") page_number = 1
```

Comment: I'll also mention `int.TryParse` in case some one tries `page=bob`

Comment: the problem is that, since the file is "List.aspx", even though I added the checking querystring and set page_number as 1, it does not get page_number sine List.aspx itself has no ?page= contents in its link.

Comment: @jon, yes, that's one of many things that could be done to improve his code, I just wanted to keep it simple

Comment: Oh thanks Darren, except for the =="", it was null state

Comment: Request.QueryString["page"] == null was the condition for the if clause

Answer (score 1):

Going above and beyond

```
//Set a default
int int_page_number = 1;

//Check there is a value in the query string for page
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["page"]))
{
     //Try to parse the query string value to an integer
     if(! int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"] , out int_page_number))
     {
         //Revert back to 1 if it fails
         int_page_number = 1;
     }
}
```

This also ensures page number is numeric.